# String Split and FileSystemEventArgs argument usage in C#

Tags: c#

In some scenario, I need to call FileWatcher onDelete function in my application.
The below code works as expected. Please let let me know if there any better way to do this.

```
         string path = @"C:\File\Test";
         string part1, part2;
         part1 = path.Substring(0, 3); //C:\\
         part2 = path.Substring(3  // File\Test
var fseArgs = new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted, part1, part2);
onDeleted(path,fseArgs); //FileWacther Delete method
```

Comment: Better? Better for what? Readability? Maintainability? Idiomatic C#? Performance? Something else?

Comment: I am new to Dot Net, trying to confirm that I am doing the right way. thaks  Oded.

Comment: You are asking for a better way of doing something (some code), but don't explain what you are trying to achieve with the code. Makes it difficult to recommend anything.

Comment: If it works just go with it. Your code looks pretty generic but I agree with @Oded

Comment: fseArgs.Fullpath  Become  C:\/File/Test. In my sample program, I am getting the ptah as C:\File\test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably `onDeleted` is your own method. What does that do? I would expect it to quite possibly be simpler to have *another* method which wasn't related to `FileSystemEventArgs`, call that directly in your "scenario", and then make your `FileSystemEventWatcher` handler call it too. Avoid coupling to `FileSystemEventWatcher` when you don't really need it.

Additionally, you shouldn't just use `Substring` like this to perform file system path manipulation - it ends up being very brittle. I strongly suggest you use the methods in [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx).

On the other hand, you haven't really told us much about your context...

Comment: If user deleted the FileSystemWatch folder itself, then I am trying to send an event for that folder. I used to check if filesystemwatch folder exist or not? if not I will send a delete event for FileSystemwatch folder

Comment: @kanden: But what does your event handler actually *do*? My point is that there's no need to go via the event handler if you could just call another method more directly.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve - is to execute some Foo logic if directory "C:\File\Test" was deleted. Why not to extract that logic to Foo() method, and call it in two places - in OnDeleted event handler, and in place where you trying to emulate Deleted event?

```
private void OnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.FullPath ==  @"C:\File\Test")
        Foo();
}

private void Foo()
{
    // Do something here 
}
```

Instead of all your code, just call `Foo();`

Comment: thanks for your review and I agree with you.
My input path is C:/Users/hpara/Desktop/HP_File/File. But inside Ondelete Function(if you refer above code), e.FullPath becomes    "C:/\Users/hpara/Desktop/HP_File/File". This breaks my path maniplulation

Comment: Actualy e.FullPath should be "C:\Users\hpara\Desktop\HP_File\File".

Comment: I found why you get 'C:/\Users/hpara/Desktop/HP_File/File'. It's because you use your original code instead of my solution and you have provided wrong path string with path delimiters '/' instead of '\'

Answer (score 0):

Check `System.IO.Path`, you will find some useful methods there.